# Select the Image from Media folder in umbraco

Tags: xslt, umbraco

im new to umbraco and  doing the maintenance for this site which i come across.i want to select the image from my Media folder,my banner from image 1 to 5 works fine (which done by someone else) however i want to put the banner for image6 which doesn't not works fine.cant locate the image logo.i have the image(banner6) below.the id:7745 which i guess since i follow the id from the last image..
[image: template]

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have been able to solve my problems, since im using Umbraco V3, all i have to do is insert that image into one of the Content Page for testing from there i can get the ID for that image and then i write the code using that ID..it works fine.

Comment: Maybe it's time to upgrade... ;) Umbraco has already moved to version 6 recently.

Answer (score 0):

You can't guess the image ID, you need to look it up in the Media section. When you hover with your mouse over the media-item in the media-tree, you can see the ID of the media in the lower  left corner:

[image]

In this case the Id of the image is 6508 and this is the Id that should be used if you want to display images hardcoded

Comment: Thanks Martijn for reply.i have done what you say above but cant display the image..<xsl:copy-of select="umbraco.library:GetMedia(1288, 0)/umbracoFile"/> <img src="/media/1288/banner6.jpg" border="0"/>...thanks in advance

Comment: The last part of your comment is what is outputted in the html? `<img src="/media/1288/banner6.jpg" border="0"/>` The syntax is correct.
You can also open the image in your browser directly by using `http://www.yoursite.com/media/1288/banner6.jpg`
If the image exists, it should be displayed. If you see nothing, you have an issue with your media library or with the name/id.

Check your medialibrary to make sure the image with this id and name exists. Also, check the html in your browser with a browser plugin like Firebug.